# Dynamic min-height in tailwind + Blazor don't is applied from three or more items

Tags: c#, .net, frontend, blazor, tailwind-css

I created a component with a div that should have a dynamic min-height value. I'm using tailwind css and Blazor.

The div is building like this:

```
<div class="flex flex-wrap gap-2 w-[250px] overflow-y-auto scroll min-h-[@GetDynamicHeightValue()] max-h-[270px]">
```

And the methodo to set a dynamic min-heigth value is this:

```
private string GetDynamicHeightValue()
{
    int filterCount = this.Filters.Count;
    int minHeight = filterCount == 0 ? 0 : (filterCount <= 2 ? 115 : (filterCount <= 4 ? 240 : 270));

    return $"{minHeight}px";
}
```

When the filter has one or two items, the min-height working very well, the value is setting as 115px:

[image]

But when the filter has three or more items, the div receive the correct value for min-h but don´t applied in Blazor component:

[image]

One detail is, if I set the min-height: 240px in element.style,on dev tools, the component working like shoulded:

[image]

Have some aditional setting to work with a dynamic value in tailwind classes and Blazor? I'm forgeting something?

Answer (score 1):

Tailwind CSS requires static class names because its stylesheets are pre-compiled during the build process. Therefore, both the class names and their corresponding values cannot be dynamically generated using variables.

```
<div
    :style="`min-height:${@GetDynamicHeightValue()}`"
></div>
```

or
if you want use tailwind

```
<div
    class="min-h-[var(--dynamicHeightValue)]"
    :style="`--dynamicHeightValue:${@GetDynamicHeightValue()}`"
></div>
```

Comment: Hello Sina, thank's for your tip. I'm not managed use this sintax with :style, but with this suggestion gave me the ideia to try use the tag style with a method, the sintax stayed like this: style="@GetDynamicHeightValue()" and the return of method like this: return $"min-height:{minHeight}px;"; and worked very well.